# Unable to retreive transaction balance before / after transfer

Tags: go-ethereum, golang

I am trying to wrap my head around the go ethereum library and sending transactions.

The issue is that I want to be able to query the balance **BEFORE** the transaction and **AFTER**. The code below gives me the same value even after making a second call to retrieve the balance and print it.

I have cut out bits of code that I think are superfluous to the question :

```
func main() {
    client, err := ethclient.Dial("https://rinkeby.infura.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    privateKey, err := crypto.HexToECDSA("49be7f9b459942977f07f99653b5b042144baefa092c5ac833d6ec9893a5b8dd")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    publicKey := privateKey.Public()
    publicKeyECDSA, ok := publicKey.(*ecdsa.PublicKey)
    if !ok {
        log.Fatal("error casting public key to ECDSA")
    }

    fromAddress := crypto.PubkeyToAddress(*publicKeyECDSA) // Under stand where this goes *publicKeyECDSA   

    balance, err := client.BalanceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress, nil)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("Address: %d \nBalance:%s\n", fromAddress.Hex(), balance) // This is the first call to retrieve the balance

    nonce, err := client.PendingNonceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    value := big.NewInt(100000000000000) // Remember to read go docs for big.NewInt

    gasLimit := uint64(21000)

    gasPrice, err := client.SuggestGasPrice(context.Background()) // What's in SuggestGas Price??
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    toAddress := common.HexToAddress("0x4592d8f8d7b001e72cb26a73e4fa1806a51ac79d")


    tx := types.NewTransaction(nonce, toAddress, value, gasLimit, gasPrice, nil) // All Parameters from Transactions in Whitepaper

    signedTx, err := types.SignTx(tx, types.HomesteadSigner{}, privateKey)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }


    err = client.SendTransaction(context.Background(), signedTx)
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    balanceAfterSend, err := client.BalanceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress, nil) // Second call to retrieve balance after transfer has been broadcasted
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("tx sent: %s\n", signedTx.Hash().Hex())
    fmt.Printf("Balance After Transfer : %d\n", balanceAfterSend) // This still gives the same value as the balance before.

}
```

When I run the program, I get the follow output in my terminal:

```
Balance:18749516000000000000
tx sent: 0x67a3b7f3d33253f2465ebc6d1cdf5b26cfac0b8d7a3c247ff184b06d46badfd2
Balance After Transfer : 18749516000000000000
```

I will appreciate any pointers on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may call [`PendingBalanceAt`](https://godoc.org/github.com/ethereum/go-ethereum/ethclient#Client.PendingBalanceAt) to get the balance of the account while it's pending confirmations.

```
pendingBalance, err := client.PendingBalanceAt(context.Background(), fromAddress)
```

Answer (score 1):

Sending a transaction doesn't mean it is mined immediately.  This is why the balance doesn't change.